# How to add transition effect on backwards

Tags: html, css

I've a problem with sliding effect on div. When it have a class `hddn` overlay will get `right: -100%;` from viewport. But when `hddn` removed it will return to viewport `right: 0`. But i need to to animate this movement. How can i solve this.

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="overlay">
         <div class="content">
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Working example [here](https://codepen.io/baagii95/pen/xpLBZR)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to do this ?

```js
$(document).on("click", function(){
  $(".overlay").toggleClass("hddn");
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
*::before, *::after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 320px;
  height: 450px;
  background: #eee;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.wrapper .overlay {
  position: relative;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
.wrapper .overlay.hddn {
  right: -100%;
  transition: right 0.4s ease-in-out;
}
.wrapper .overlay.hddn .content {
  right: -100%;
}
.wrapper .content {
  width: 80%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #e7e7e7;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  transition: right 0.4s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="overlay hddn">
    <div class="content">
      I am content    
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```